# Cannot login to the UbuntuOne webpage

Tags: ubuntu-one

I cannot login to the one.ubuntu.com page from my Ubuntu PC (11.10 + Firefox). When entering the email address and password it replies with a "Stale Request" page.
From other PCs with Windows + Firefox it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cookies/cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I have 10.04 with Firefox (3.6.24 at time of writing) on a desktop machine.  I have the same problem as described above - logging in works from Windows and other Ubuntu machines.  Clearing the cookies and cache did not work, and neither did removing and reinstalling as detailed in the FAQ on this site.

I subsequently discovered that the following appears to work - in `about:config`, find the following key:

```
network.http.sendRefererHeader
```

I selected **reset** which changed the value from 0 to 2.  I don't know the correct value, or the consequence of changing it.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Derek and edited by Peachy in another answer here, and also discovered by me at the [launchpad-users team mailing list archive](https://lists.launchpad.net/launchpad-users/msg06505.html), the problem is referrer headers (or lack thereof).  Ubuntu One Single SignOn service uses referrer headers to protect against Cross Site Request Forgery and therefore this feature must be enabled in your browser in order to log in using their service.

To enable this feature, you must type `about:config` in your Firefox or Iceweasel browser URL bar and then after agreeing to the scary warning page, enter into the search box the following key:

`network.http.sendRefererHeader`

Once this value is located, you can right click on it and select `Reset` from the menu that pops up in order to restore it to the Mozilla default of `2`, or you can double click on it and change the value from `0` to `1` or `2`.  This enables the sending of referrer headers.

If you wish to still have control over this feature for privacy purposes, then you can use an addon such as [Referrer Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/referrer-control/) to allow you to create custom rules for individual sites and/or set a default referrer policy for all sites.  Documentation for that addon is available at:

`https://github.com/muzuiget/referrer_control/wiki`

(Sorry if you have to copy and paste the preceding link but I have not enough "reputation" to post more than two links.  If anyone with more "reputation" wishes to edit this answer to properly linkify that last link there, feel free.)